# How can I prompts loop in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want the main.js loop to be re-selectable when the user has selected option.

Here is the code.

main.js

```
const prompts = require('prompts');
var option = require('./option.js');

(async () => {
  const response = await prompts({

    type: 'select',
    name: 'value',
    message: 'choice',
    
    choices: [
      { title: 'option1', description: 'option1 description', value: '1' },
     
      { title: 'exit',  description: 'exit from script',value: '0' }

    ],
    initial: 1

    
  }
  
  
  
  ).then(response => {


if(response.value == 1){


  console.info('you select option1');
option.option1()

// i want to run main.js again here
}
else {
  console.info('you select exit');
// i want to exit from main.js 
}
  });

})();
```

option.js

```
module.exports = {


    option1:function() {
        console.log("You have selected option 1")
    }
}
```

When the user has selected option1, after the option.js script's function is done, I would like it to return to the new options page.

I've tried many ways but I still can't find a way. What can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the solution to your problem? Also notice when using await, dont use then.

```
const prompts = require('prompts');
var option = require('./option.js');


async function prompt () {
 
  const response = await prompts({

    type: 'select',
    name: 'value',
    message: 'choice',
    
    choices: [
      { title: 'option1', description: 'option1 description', value: '1' },
     
      { title: 'exit',  description: 'exit from script',value: '0' }

    ],
    initial: 1
  })
  
  return response.value === '1'?option.option1() & prompt():false
}
prompt()
```

Comment: This solved my problem ty :)

Comment: Can you please explain more why don't use then when using await?

Comment: When declaring an `async function`, inside of it you can use `await`. For example, If I don't want to declare it as async, you have to use `then`. In this example `function prompt () { getSomeData().then(response => { if (response.value === '1') option.option1() & prompt() }) }`So you're not using await. Await and then give the same result but in different ways. The variable that you assign to the async call, `const response = await prompts()` would have the same value as `.then(response)`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge.  :)

Comment: You can see more here [async/await](https://dev.to/masteringjs/using-then-vs-async-await-in-javascript-2pma)

Comment: bother you to explain `response.value === '1'?option.option1() & prompt():false` ? I've only used if else , I tried to understand but I don't know what it is and what its call.

Comment: because I have  More than 1 option but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: That's [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Acts as an if/else and can be used inline or when defining a variable. First you set a condition, then `?`. If the condition is true it runs the first expression, if not the second after `:`. For example, `if (1 === 1){ console.log('equal') } else { console.log(' not equal') }` and `1===1?console.log('equal') :  console.log(' not equal') ` would reproduce the same output. When applying to a variable: `const areEqual = 1===1?true :  false` where `areEqual` would be true.

Comment: ty, you help me a lot  :)